# Over-qualifying CSS3 selectors necessary to make background-position work?

Tags: css

I stumbled upon this [stunning CSS3 3D animation](http://www.baloziproductions.com/WrapImageAroundCylinder) and viewed it in the following browsers:

- Safari 9.0.1
- Chrome 47.0.2526.106
- Firefox 43.0.1

I was experimenting with the code a site provides (it's a single HTML page  that doesn't require external files, just makes a few valid external HTTP references). I noticed there are CSS statements `.strip .a` `.strip .b`, etc...

From what I thought I understand, specifying `.strip` on those lines is over-qualifying the CSS selector, as there are no other cases of class `.a`, class `.b`, etc...  to introduce any ambiguity - those class names are virtually identical to id selectors in this case since each refers to only one HTML tag.

However, when I remove the `.strip` from those selectors (e.g. make the selectors mere `.a`, `.b`, etc...), the respective CSS `background-position` offsets seem to stop working, and the image strips for those lines display only the leading rectangular area of the image, instead of slices at respective specified background-position offsets.  The result is the same in all the aforementioned browsers.

I provided an example of the code at the end of the question and the corresponding screen snapshot exhibiting the artifacts produced. In the code below, I removed  `.strip` from the selectors of the `.a`, `.b`, `.c`, and `.d` lines. You can see the strips those four seem to not be positioned properly in the image shown below.

[image]

Is that a bug in webkit, mozkit, or is there something I don't understand about CSS regarding this kind of selector?

```css
body {
  background: #000;
  color: rgb(236, 132, 57)
}
h1 {
  font: small-caps 167% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif
}
#container {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 450px;
  width: 550px;
  -moz-perspective: 900px;
  -webkit-perspective: 900
}
#container:hover * {
  -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused
}
#frame {
  width: 33px;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;  /* translate must be last */
  -moz-transform: rotateX(35deg) rotateY(45deg) rotateZ(15deg) translate3d(325px, -70px, 50px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(35deg) rotateY(45deg) rotateZ(15deg) translate3d(325px, -70px, 50px)
}
.strip {
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-animation: spin 25s infinite linear;
  -webkit-animation: spin 25s infinite linear
}
.strip div {
  position: absolute;
  background: #000 url(http://baloziproductions.com/thailand-sunrise.jpg);  /* background image is 792px 320px, try with green-hills or thailand-sunrise.jpg */
  border: solid rgb(145, 87, 0);
  border-width: thin 0;
  height: 320px;
  width: 34px;
  opacity: 1;
}
.a {
  background-position: 0 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.b {
  background-position: 759px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(15deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(15deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.c {
  background-position: 726px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(30deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(30deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.d {
  background-position: 693px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(45deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(45deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.strip .e {
  background-position: 660px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(60deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(60deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.strip .f {
  background-position: 627px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(75deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(75deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.strip .g {
  background-position: 594px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.strip .h {
  background-position: 561px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(105deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(105deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.strip .i {
  background-position: 528px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(120deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(120deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.strip .j {
  background-position: 495px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(135deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(135deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.strip .k {
  background-position: 462px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(150deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(150deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.strip .l {
  background-position: 429px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(165deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(165deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.strip .m {
  background-position: 396px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.strip .n {
  background-position: 363px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(195deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(195deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.strip .o {
  background-position: 330px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(210deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(210deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.strip .p {
  background-position: 297px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(225deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(225deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.strip .q {
  background-position: 264px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(240deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(240deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.strip .r {
  background-position: 231px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(255deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(255deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.strip .s {
  background-position: 198px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(270deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(270deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.strip .t {
  background-position: 165px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(285deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(285deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.strip .u {
  background-position: 132px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(300deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(300deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.strip .v {
  background-position: 99px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(315deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(315deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.strip .w {
  background-position: 66px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(330deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(330deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.strip .x {
  background-position: 33px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(345deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(345deg) translateZ(124px)
}
@-moz-keyframes spin {
  from {
    -moz-transform: rotateY(0)
  }
  to {
    -moz-transform: rotateY(-360deg)
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0)
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-360deg)
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h1>Image Wrapped Around A Spinning strip</h1>
  <div id="frame">
    <div class="strip">
      <div class="a"></div>
      <div class="b"></div>
      <div class="c"></div>
      <div class="d"></div>
      <div class="e"></div>
      <div class="f"></div>
      <div class="g"></div>
      <div class="h"></div>
      <div class="i"></div>
      <div class="j"></div>
      <div class="k"></div>
      <div class="l"></div>
      <div class="m"></div>
      <div class="n"></div>
      <div class="o"></div>
      <div class="p"></div>
      <div class="q"></div>
      <div class="r"></div>
      <div class="s"></div>
      <div class="t"></div>
      <div class="u"></div>
      <div class="v"></div>
      <div class="w"></div>
      <div class="x"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The overly specific selector **is required because of how background is specified within `.strip div` selector**.

```css
.strip div {
  position: absolute;
  background: #000 url(http://baloziproductions.com/thailand-sunrise.jpg); /* this causes the problem */
  border: solid rgb(145, 87, 0);
  border-width: thin 0;
  height: 320px;
  width: 34px;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

When the `background` shorthand property is used to set a background, the UA sets a value for all the longhand `background-*` properties. For those longhand properties where a value is explicitly provided (like `background-color`, `background-image`) that value is used. For all the others, the default value is used. The default for `background-position` is `0% 0%`.

> From [W3C Spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-backgrounds-3/#the-background): <sup>(emphasis is mine)</sup>
>
> The ‘background’ property is a shorthand property for setting most background properties at the same place in the style sheet. The number of comma-separated items defines the number of background layers. Given a valid declaration, for each layer the shorthand **first sets** the corresponding layer of each of ‘background-image’, ‘background-position’, ‘background-size’, ‘background-repeat’, ‘background-origin’, ‘background-clip’ and ‘background-attachment’ **to that property's initial value, then assigns any explicit values** specified for this layer in the declaration.

So, one `background-position` setting already exists on `.strip div` implicitly. When the `.strip` is removed from the `.a`, `.b`, `.c` selectors, they become less specific compared to `.strip div` and so doesn't modify the default background position.

The specificity of `.strip div` is 011 as it has only one class selector and one type selector. That for `.strip .a` is 020 as it has 2 class selectors and no type or ID selector. Specificity of `.a` is 010 as it has only one class selector and no type or ID selector.

**Problematic Snippet:** (Uses shorthand property in `.strip div` without `.strip` before `.a`,`.b` etc)

```css
body {
  background: #000;
  color: rgb(236, 132, 57)
}
h1 {
  font: small-caps 167% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif
}
#container {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 450px;
  width: 550px;
  -moz-perspective: 900px;
  -webkit-perspective: 900
}
#container:hover * {
  -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused
}
#frame {
  width: 33px;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform: rotateX(35deg) rotateY(45deg) rotateZ(15deg) translate3d(325px, -70px, 50px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(35deg) rotateY(45deg) rotateZ(15deg) translate3d(325px, -70px, 50px)
}
.strip {
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-animation: spin 25s infinite linear;
  -webkit-animation: spin 25s infinite linear
}
.strip div {
  position: absolute;
  background: #000 url(http://baloziproductions.com/thailand-sunrise.jpg);
  border: solid rgb(145, 87, 0);
  border-width: thin 0;
  height: 320px;
  width: 34px;
  opacity: 1;
}
.a {
  background-position: 0 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.b {
  background-position: 759px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(15deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(15deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.c {
  background-position: 726px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(30deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(30deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.d {
  background-position: 693px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(45deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(45deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.e {
  background-position: 660px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(60deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(60deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.f {
  background-position: 627px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(75deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(75deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.g {
  background-position: 594px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.h {
  background-position: 561px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(105deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(105deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.i {
  background-position: 528px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(120deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(120deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.j {
  background-position: 495px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(135deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(135deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.k {
  background-position: 462px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(150deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(150deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.l {
  background-position: 429px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(165deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(165deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.m {
  background-position: 396px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.n {
  background-position: 363px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(195deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(195deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.o {
  background-position: 330px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(210deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(210deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.p {
  background-position: 297px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(225deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(225deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.q {
  background-position: 264px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(240deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(240deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.r {
  background-position: 231px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(255deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(255deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.s {
  background-position: 198px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(270deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(270deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.t {
  background-position: 165px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(285deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(285deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.u {
  background-position: 132px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(300deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(300deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.v {
  background-position: 99px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(315deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(315deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.w {
  background-position: 66px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(330deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(330deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.x {
  background-position: 33px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(345deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(345deg) translateZ(124px)
}
@-moz-keyframes spin {
  from {
    -moz-transform: rotateY(0)
  }
  to {
    -moz-transform: rotateY(-360deg)
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0)
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-360deg)
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h1>Image Wrapped Around A Spinning strip</h1>
  <div id="frame">
    <div class="strip">
      <div class="a"></div>
      <div class="b"></div>
      <div class="c"></div>
      <div class="d"></div>
      <div class="e"></div>
      <div class="f"></div>
      <div class="g"></div>
      <div class="h"></div>
      <div class="i"></div>
      <div class="j"></div>
      <div class="k"></div>
      <div class="l"></div>
      <div class="m"></div>
      <div class="n"></div>
      <div class="o"></div>
      <div class="p"></div>
      <div class="q"></div>
      <div class="r"></div>
      <div class="s"></div>
      <div class="t"></div>
      <div class="u"></div>
      <div class="v"></div>
      <div class="w"></div>
      <div class="x"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Instead of using the shorthand `background` property, if `background-color`, `background-image` were directly used then `.strip` is not required before `.a`, `.b`, `.c` etc because there is no `background-position` in a higher specificity selector.

```css
.strip div {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #000; /* changed */
  background-image: url(http://baloziproductions.com/thailand-sunrise.jpg); /* changed */
  border: solid rgb(145, 87, 0);
  border-width: thin 0;
  height: 320px;
  width: 34px;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

**Fixed Snippet:** (Uses longhand properties in `.strip div` and no `.strip` before `.a`, `.b` etc)

```css
body {
  background: #000;
  color: rgb(236, 132, 57)
}
h1 {
  font: small-caps 167% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif
}
#container {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 450px;
  width: 550px;
  -moz-perspective: 900px;
  -webkit-perspective: 900
}
#container:hover * {
  -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused
}
#frame {
  width: 33px;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  /* translate must be last */
  -moz-transform: rotateX(35deg) rotateY(45deg) rotateZ(15deg) translate3d(325px, -70px, 50px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(35deg) rotateY(45deg) rotateZ(15deg) translate3d(325px, -70px, 50px)
}
.strip {
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-animation: spin 25s infinite linear;
  -webkit-animation: spin 25s infinite linear
}
.strip div {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #000;
  background-image: url(http://baloziproductions.com/thailand-sunrise.jpg);
  border: solid rgb(145, 87, 0);
  border-width: thin 0;
  height: 320px;
  width: 34px;
  opacity: 1;
}
.a {
  background-position: 0 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.b {
  background-position: 759px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(15deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(15deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.c {
  background-position: 726px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(30deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(30deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.d {
  background-position: 693px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(45deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(45deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.e {
  background-position: 660px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(60deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(60deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.f {
  background-position: 627px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(75deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(75deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.g {
  background-position: 594px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.h {
  background-position: 561px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(105deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(105deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.i {
  background-position: 528px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(120deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(120deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.j {
  background-position: 495px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(135deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(135deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.k {
  background-position: 462px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(150deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(150deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.l {
  background-position: 429px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(165deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(165deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.m {
  background-position: 396px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.n {
  background-position: 363px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(195deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(195deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.o {
  background-position: 330px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(210deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(210deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.p {
  background-position: 297px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(225deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(225deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.q {
  background-position: 264px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(240deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(240deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.r {
  background-position: 231px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(255deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(255deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.s {
  background-position: 198px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(270deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(270deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.t {
  background-position: 165px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(285deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(285deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.u {
  background-position: 132px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(300deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(300deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.v {
  background-position: 99px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(315deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(315deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.w {
  background-position: 66px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(330deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(330deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.x {
  background-position: 33px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(345deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(345deg) translateZ(124px)
}
@-moz-keyframes spin {
  from {
    -moz-transform: rotateY(0)
  }
  to {
    -moz-transform: rotateY(-360deg)
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0)
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-360deg)
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h1>Image Wrapped Around A Spinning strip</h1>
  <div id="frame">
    <div class="strip">
      <div class="a"></div>
      <div class="b"></div>
      <div class="c"></div>
      <div class="d"></div>
      <div class="e"></div>
      <div class="f"></div>
      <div class="g"></div>
      <div class="h"></div>
      <div class="i"></div>
      <div class="j"></div>
      <div class="k"></div>
      <div class="l"></div>
      <div class="m"></div>
      <div class="n"></div>
      <div class="o"></div>
      <div class="p"></div>
      <div class="q"></div>
      <div class="r"></div>
      <div class="s"></div>
      <div class="t"></div>
      <div class="u"></div>
      <div class="v"></div>
      <div class="w"></div>
      <div class="x"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Huge help. Alternatively, a heavy-handed potentially ignorant approach to hacking specificity in this case is changing from class to id (`.a` → `#a`).  I was uninformed about CSS specificity calculations. How CSS declaration default values parlay is a meta consideration where the analysis by seasoned expert like yourself is where the *real* education happens!  Specificity is so fundamental and important, that more tutorials about CSS should present that topic up-front.  Supplemental info:  https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/ (links to more detail background at end of article).

Comment: @nerdistcolony: Yep, changing the class to an id and using that selector would also work because it would put a 1 in the 100th position. The [specificity calculator available in this site](https://specificity.keegan.st/) should also help. Happy that the answer helped you :)

Comment: Just bumping into this again with my new handle (@clearlight), and appreciating what a great answer you gave. Again many thanks. Very educational about how to think about CSS.